# How to replicate Cloudant DB in 2 Bluemix env

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloudant

I have application deployed in both US South and London Bluemix env to improve reliability. I would like to synch the cloudant db in both of these envs. In the setting up of the replication job, I have problems in defining the source DB and target DB. 
I have "the database doesn't exist" error when I set up the US South replication job, I used the url from the environment variables in the London env of the Cloudant DB service as the source db.
Can you help me to define where to get the target and source DB for the replication please?

Thanks.

Jen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be in this format:
https://$USERNAME:$PASSWORD@$REMOTE_USERNAME.cloudant.com/**$DATABASE_NAME**

Notice the $DATABASE_NAME at the end.

The URL field in the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable will not have the database name at the end, because the database is something you create.